# Why isn't JobScope and StepScope available from an MVC thread?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm getting `Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedTarget.processVlsCasesJob': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton` from a job factory class. The factory is where the job and step beans are created in the correct job/step scopes from a bean invoked during main application start up.

```
@Component("processVlsCasesJobFactory")
public class ProcessVlsCasesJobFactoryImpl
extends BatchJobFactoryAncestorImpl 
implements ProcessVlsCasesJobFactory {
...
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ProcessVlsCasesJob processVlsCasesJob() {
    return new ProcessVlsCasesJobImpl();
}
    ...
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ProcessVlsCasesProcessCases processVlsCasesProcessCases() {
    return new ProcessVlsCasesProcessCasesImpl();
}
    ...
    // other bean methods creating the step objects
```

Any attempt to allow Spring to auto-register any bean in the Job/Steps scope fails with that type of error. If those scopes are only available when (I guess) a job is running, how do I "create" the bean in the scope from the thread of the main MVC application running in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't JobScope and StepScope available from an MVC thread?

Those are custom scopes specific to Spring Batch, they are not part of Spring MVC. You need to specifically register them (or use `@EnableBatchProcessing` to have them automatically registered)

> how do I "create" the bean in the scope from the thread of the main MVC application running in Tomcat?

The main thread (processing the web request) should call a `JobLauncher` configured with an asynchronous `TaskExecutor` so that the batch job is executed in a separate thread. Please see the [Running Jobs from within a Web Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer) section which provides more details and a code example of how to do that.

Comment: I already have a class with: `@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing public class BatchModeConfiguration implements Serializable' doing all that, including a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. If having @EBP set on a such a class is supposed to be enough to active the Job/Step Scopes, why am I getting that error when the job/step classes are annotated as being in Job/Step scopes? **Currently**, my job beans are scoped singleton and I can start async jobs.

Comment: Apparently, the Job/Step scope isn't available unless a job is actually running. Annotating jobs as scope=job/step fails at deployment (war) time because Spring says the scope isn't available.

Comment: I just reconfigured my "job" class as singleton and all the other classes (reader,write) as job/step scope. Though Spring finds them during deployment, even registering the job into the repository, during execution (from JobLauncher) when the injected default (MVC) applicationContext is asked for a Job/Step scoped bean, it throws the same error, saying that those scopes aren't available from the current thread - even though the thread is a new asynchronous one from the JobLauncher's TaskExecutor instance. ...

Comment: ... 
So, how exactly does one instruct the jobLauncher to access "new" application context that DOES have access or can create the Job/Step scopes?

Comment: Job/Step scope beans are lazily created until a Job/Step is actually running, this is necessary for late binding of job parameters and attributes from the job/step execution contexts. In addition to the documentation link I gave in my answer, you can find another code example of launching jobs from a web application [here](https://github.com/mminella/LearningSpringBatch/tree/master/src/startingAJob).

Comment: Yes, but the documentation is two paragraphs long and only mentions asynchronous in passing. Your code example isn't a web app (JSP/JSF) but a RESTful example. I have brought SB into an existing MVC web app with a UI that allows the user to start a job on demand, supplying required parameters. The thread runs fine if the beans are all Singleton scope. If I mark the beans as job/step scope, the error returns. So clearly the "asynchronous thread" created by the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor I configured into the jobLauncher knows nothing about/isn't allowed to use the job/step scopes.

Comment: The crux of my problem seems to be that job/step scope isn't LIVE until a job is running and yet using AC.getBean() to create them in the those scopes from within a Singleton scoped SimpleJob descendant doesn't work.

I noticed the org.springframework.batch.core.configuration .support.GenericApplicationContextFactory class. Am I going to have to create a SB-specific ApplicationContext for jobs to run in along side the main MVC app's AC?

Comment: Nothing in regards to this?

Comment: for this kind of issues, it is difficult to help without reproducing the problem. Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on github or somewhere online and I will do my best to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer: @EnableBatchProcessing doesn't work within an MVC application context. In the @Configuration bean I created to configure SB (with DB2) and set up all the SB beans (like jobLauncher), I added:

```
jobScope = new JobScope();
jobScope.setAutoProxy(Boolean.FALSE);
jobScope.setName(JobScoped.SCOPE_NAME);
((ConfigurableBeanFactory)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory())
    .registerScope(JobScoped.SCOPE_NAME, jobScope);

stepScope = new StepScope();
stepScope.setAutoProxy(Boolean.FALSE);
stepScope.setName(StepScoped.SCOPE_NAME);
((ConfigurableBeanFactory)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory())
    .registerScope(StepScoped.SCOPE_NAME, stepScope);
```

Then the two scopes were finally available at run time and the job/step scoped beans were registered at deployment and ran properly.

Was @EBP added as part of Spring Boot? Is it only supposed to be used via a command line tool?